# Is this weird "such that" notation valid?

Tags: notation

I've seen that the phrase "such that" can be notated as a $|$ or  a $:$, specially when you are using a set builder notation. My Geometry teacher also occasionally uses an $\in$ but "backwards" when stating theorems.

But now my Calculus teacher uses a weird symbol that I've never seen before. It's like an normal uppercase E, but "laying down", "rotated -90°", or like three parallel vertical lines with a horizontal line over them, like this:

[image]

Does this symbol even exist?
Have you seen it before? Where?
Is it correct to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey An E laying down :-p.

Comment: Hope this helps: [link](http://imgur.com/UDu5xp2)

Comment: I have never heard of such a symbol.

Comment: @Ricardo, can you give an example, where your teacher used this?

Answer (score 2):

I've searched over 900 symbols using [this tool](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and I wasn't able to find such one, nor have I ever seen it used.

My advice would be to just ask your professor if he invented that symbol, and if he did, for what reason.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen it used before, not sure where. Doesn't seem to have caught on. It's $\ni$ = "\ni". [See this tex question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24940/how-to-make-a-backwards-in).

Comment: It's an 'E' rotated **-90** degrees. NOT 180. So it looks like an squared M.

Comment: @MikePierce OP said "backwards" but I guess changed their mind, so this answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: When OP said backwards, they were describing a different symbol used for "such that". The actual question begins in paragraph two of the post. You should read the entire question before answering.

Comment: @MikePierce yeah, thanks for the advice.